# How to enable openCV training of haar on Nvidia GPU?

Tags: opencv, gpu, nvidia

In OpenCV How to enable training of haar on Nvidia GPU. can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it isn't implemented:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/179831/how-opencv_traincascade-can-using-gpu/

Comment: Clearly, I'm not able to understand from your example. please tell me HOW to enable openCV training of haar on Nvidia GPU.

Comment: According to that post. You can not.

Comment: Is there any other option to do that.